# How to enable antialias/multisampling when rendering to framebuffer with stencil buffer for webgl2?

Tags: framebuffer, antialiasing, webgl2, stencil-buffer, twgl.js

I add `samples: 4` and change `gl.RGBA` to `gl.RGBA4` to enable antialias of first framebuffer attachment:

```js
const framebufferInfo = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(gl, [
  { format: gl.RGBA4, type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, min: gl.LINEAR, wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, samples: 4 },
  { format: gl.DEPTH_STENCIL, samples: 4 },
], canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

I got error of `renderbufferStorageMultisample: internalformat invalid for samples > 0`.